# how to assing values from other view controller to custom UIView in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have iphone app in which i am using EASYGRAPH api for graph i have Display View created where i draw percentage and graph chart i want that value in this may come dynamically when app is created.Like i have perecentage 78% then how should assign this values which is anohter view in my code to the display view

Display View

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 @interface Display : UIView {

 }

 @end



  #import "Display.h"
  #import "ECGraph.h"
 @implementation Display


 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
 if (self) {
    // Initialization code.
 }
 return self;
  }


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code


CGContextRef _context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

ECGraph *graph = [[ECGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500,-320,320, 200) withContext:_context isPortrait:NO];


ECGraphItem *item1 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];
item1.isPercentage = YES;
item1.yValue = 80;
```

I want the percentage to be set in following way totoalpercentage which is in my GraohsViewCOntroller whose nin is the DisplayView

Like this

```
    item1.yValue=totalpercentage;
item1.width = 35;
item1.name = @"item1";

ECGraphItem *item2 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];
item2.isPercentage = YES;
item2.yValue =17;
item2.width = 35; 
item2.name = @"item2";
/*
 ECGraphItem *item3 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];
 item3.isPercentage = YES;
 item3.yValue = 45;
 item3.width = 35;
 item3.name = @"item3";

 ECGraphItem *item4 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];
 item4.isPercentage = YES;
 item4.yValue = 78.6;
 item4.width = 35;
 item4.name = @"item4";

 ECGraphItem *item5 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];
 item5.isPercentage = YES;
 item5.yValue = 94.45;
 item5.width = 35;
 item5.name = @"item5"; */


NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:item1,item2,nil];
[graph setXaxisTitle:@"name"];
[graph setYaxisTitle:@"Percentage"];
[graph setGraphicTitle:@"Histogram"];
[graph setDelegate:self];
[graph setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:220/255.0 green:220/255.0 blue:220/255.0 alpha:1]];
[graph drawHistogramWithItems:items lineWidth:2 color:[UIColor blackColor]];

     }
```

GraphicsViewController

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

[self createGraph];

NSArray *percentages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"80",@"17", nil];

[display setPercentageArray:percentages];
float costtoclient=[costToClient floatValue];
float markup=[clinicalMarkup floatValue];
float ProfitForCerenia=costtoclient/markup;
    float totalProfit=costtoclient-ProfitForCerenia;
int result = (int)ceilf(totalProfit );
    NSString*cerniaProfitTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",result];
[profitForEachCereniaButton setTitle:cerniaProfitTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];

int one=[valueOne intValue];
int two=[valueTwo intValue];
int three=[valueThree intValue];
int four=[valueFour intValue];
    int dogsPerMonthCarSickness=one+two+three+four;
    int dogsPerYear=dogsPerMonthCarSickness*12;
int annualprofit=dogsPerYear*result;
NSString*annualProfitButtonTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",annualprofit];

[currentAnnualProfitFromCereniaButton setTitle:annualProfitButtonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];

int otherthancerenia=two+three+four;
    int visitclinicpermonth=[perMonth intValue];
     int otherthanCereniaAnnaul=otherthancerenia*12;

int potentialprofit=otherthanCereniaAnnaul*annualprofit;

NSString*potentialProfitTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",potentialprofit];

[potentialProfit setTitle:potentialProfitTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     int cereniaUsedForCarSickness=[cerenia intValue];
 int cereniapercentageCal=cereniaUsedForCarSickness*100;
      int cereniaPercentageCalculate=cereniapercentageCal/dogsPerMonthCarSickness;
  NSString*cereniaUsedForCarSicknessTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cereniaPercentageCalculate];

 [cereniaUsedForMotionSicknessButton setTitle:cereniaUsedForCarSicknessTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];


int otherthancereniaperc=100-cereniaPercentageCalculate;

int otherthancereniapercentage=otherthancereniaperc;


//int remaining=dogsPerMonthCarSickness-cereniaUsedForCarSickness;
NSString*remainingTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",otherthancereniapercentage];
```

//  [otherDrugsButton setTitle:remainingTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [otherDrugsButton setTitle:remainingTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];

```
dogsPerYearForCarSickness=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dogsPerYear];


     [dogsPerYearForCarSicknessButton setTitle:dogsPerYearForCarSickness forState:UIControlStateNormal];


 NSString *titledogsPerMonthForCarSicknessButton =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dogsPerMonthCarSickness];



[dogsPerMonthForCarSicknessButton setTitle:titledogsPerMonthForCarSicknessButton forState:UIControlStateNormal]
     int visitclinicperyear=visitclinicpermonth*12;

     float maxprofit=visitclinicperyear*0.17*result;
 int maximumprofit = (int)ceilf(maxprofit);
 NSString*maximumProfitTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",maximumprofit];
[maximumProfit setTitle:maximumProfitTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

  -(void)createGraph{


PieClass *myPieClass=[[PieClass alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,440,320,230)];

myPieClass.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

myPieClass.itemArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:valueOne,valueTwo,valueThree,valueFour, nil];

myPieClass.myColorArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIColor blueColor],[UIColor redColor],[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor brownColor], nil];

myPieClass.radius=100;

[self.view addSubview:myPieClass];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to pass percentage of every item to DisplayView, make a method in DisplayView,

-(void) setPercentageArray:(NSArray*) array

then call this method from GraphsViewController and pass array like,

NSArray *percentages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"80", @"75", @"90", nil];

make a class member variable in DisplayView, and 'setPercentageArray' this method will set that variable.

use that array for respective items.

**Edit:**

in .h of DisplayView

```
@interface Display : UIView {

 NSArray *percentages;

}
-(void) setPercentageArray:(NSArray*) array;
@end
```

in DisplayView.m , add this method,

```
-(void) setPercentageArray:(NSArray*) array
{
    percentages = array;
}
```

in drawRect method, u can do like this,

```
 ECGraphItem *item1 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];
 item1.isPercentage = YES;
 item1.yValue = 80;     
 item1.yValue= [percentages objectAtIndex:0];
 item1.width = 35;
 item1.name = @"item1";

 ECGraphItem *item2 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];
 item2.isPercentage = [percentages objectAtIndex:1]
 item2.yValue =17;
 item2.width = 35; 
 item2.name = @"item2";
```

Comment: and how to call this method from GraphsViewController [self getPercantgeArray];

Comment: its ok but i want to give these percnetage values in item1.yvalue=[percentages objectAtIndex:0]; it gives error incampitable type for setValue .yvalue

Comment: try this,     [[percentages objectAtIndex:0] intValue]

Comment: but how to call this method from GraphicsViewController it crahses over there  i am calling in this way [self setPercenatgeArray:percentages]

Comment: u'll need to have instance of Display View in GraphicsViewController, and with that instance u'll call method , like  [displayViewInstance setPercenatgeArray:percentages]

Comment: how to declaer instande like class object

Comment: please can you help me out in this last step

Comment: u must be using Display View somewhere in GraphicsViewController, use the same instance..
if not, u can create one like, Display *instance = [[Display alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];

Comment: not solving again same issue may write code for my graphics view controller you can see then

Comment: u are calling method with,  [display setPercentageArray:percentages]; but where you created the object 'display' , i cant get this from code

Comment: i have declared display in .h file Display*display